# Async Boost writing to Java Socket - incoming byte array sometimes partially 0?

Tags: java, c++, boost, tcp, boost-asio

I have some C++ code that is writing to a socket that is being read from by a Java program.

The C++ program uses boost::async_write to transfer the bytes, and they are then read by the Java program.  The first 4 bytes of the async_write call correspond to the size of the underlying data segment. Because the size is explicitly determined by this header, the Java code can fill a byte array that is the size of the actual data using a BufferedInputStream's "read" method.

Although this seems to work fine almost every time, sometimes the byte array read by the InputStream contains zeroed out data for the end of its buffer. About 1 out of every 50000 messages is "corrupted" in this way. The place in the buffer where the zeroed out data starts varies. Although I can catch this and throw out the message I am wondering if this is expected performance? I have tried this where both programs are communicating through a socket on localhost and still have the problem.

I do not believe the bytes being written in the C++ program are going out of scope, because the are temporarily stored on a queue until the "handle_write" returns (from the async_write)

The C++ program only has a single thread executing the io_service.

The Java program is executing the reading in a single thread as well.

I did not detect any memory leaks in either program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, this bug is on the reading side. Are you sure you actually read the entire message?

Comment: You are correct it turns out that BufferedInputStream's "read" method was not filling all of the bytes in the byte[] it was supposed to fill. I am not sure why this happens, but I appreciate the good advice.

Answer (score 0):

I have written many Socket program using IO and NIO and these sort of problems are always caused by a bug.  I suggest you try connecting Java to Java to test whether the bug is on the Java or C++ side.